# Does a generically injective morphism of schemes have a section?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a generically injective, finite morphism between projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, with $Y$ non-singular. Does $f$ have a section i.e., a morphism $g:Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g:Y \to Y$ is the identity?

If not true in general, is there any known condition under which $f$ has a section?

**EDIT.** The map $f$ is assumed to be dominant.

Comment: Presumably you want to assume that $f$ is dominant, or else this is trivially false.  If $f$ is dominant and generically injective, then $f$ is birational.  A finite, birational morphism with normal target $Y$ is an isomorphism by Zariski's Main Theorem (classical formulation).

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. Yes, I assume $f$ to be dominant. Can we say something if we drop the assumption on finite morphism and replace it with projective morphism. The picture I have in mind is that when $f$ is generically injective except for a codimension $2$ locus where the fibers are rational curves.

Comment: With "projective morphism" it seems to me that the answer is *no* in such a generality. Take the blow-up $\pi \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ of the plane at at a point: of course it has no regular sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ is normal, then every finite generically injective dominant morphism $f:X \to Y$ is an isomorphism. Indeed, take an open affine subset $U = Spec~ A$ of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(Y) = Spec~B$ where $B$ is integral over $A$. Since $A$ is integrally closed and $A,B$ have the same field of fractions, $A = B$.

So the answer to your question is: ``Yes, always!''

Comment: "A,B have the same field of fractions" is true over complex numbers, but it requires an additional explanation why is so since over a field of positive characteristic it is simply not true. Indeed, take a Frobenius morphism.
What we can prove in general is that $f$ is an universal homeomorphism, by proving it is injective, what is equivalent to being finite, radicial, and surjective. Then, in char=0, radicial means birational, and we are done.